# Bash - argument not working

Tags: bash

Hello I am running a javac command (lstf is a file)

```
javac @$lstf
```

For some reason, I get an error saying `javac: file not found: path/to/dir/*.java`. Whenever I type the args in manually in Terminal javac works.

Here is the code:

```
mkdir "$out"

cd src
scan

"$cc" $cflags -d "../$out" @${lstf}
rm -rf $lstf
cd ../
```

scan is the function that generates all the paths in the file $lstf - it works fine

Comment: Can you show the rest of the script or commands leading up to this?

Comment: What is the intended significance of the `@` sign?

Comment: Maybe if you do: javac @"$lstf"

Comment: So if I understand this right, you have a file called "$lstf" (dollar sign included) containing names of java files to be compiled? Is this correct? Can you show us the contents of this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to say `javac @foo`, and `lstf` = `foo`?

Whenever you are in a situation where variable names are hard to decipher, you can use `${var}` syntax instead of just `$var`:

```
javac @${lstf}
```

Comment: Can you show us the script and explain better what you're trying to do? I'm not actually sure why you have the `@` there in the first place. Are you trying to do use "$@"? Please edit your question to clarify exactly what you're trying to do. That way we can help you instead of simply guessing.

Answer (score 0):

If your file path is store in lstf variable, just called it

```
javac "$lstf"
```

Comment: This is wrong as @anyfile means that javac must read a set of file names stored in anyfile, but not to compile anyfile itself.